# Wordpress - Get custom page templates by post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have this code that displays all the custom page templates in my theme directory...

```
 <?php 
    $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
    foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
        echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
    }
 ?>
```

However, I would like to only display the custom templates available to a certain post type. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260372/how-can-i-force-custom-post-type-to-use-a-specific-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
<?php 
    $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates($post = null, $post_type = 'page'); 
    foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
        echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code your active theme functions.php file

```
$page_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template'
    )
);
```